# I have an issue that my flutter app with firebase is not working

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

After running the following commands I have this kind of issue.

I was expecting to find the output, but unfortunately I am not able to find and proceed.

I run this command:

```
PS C:\Users\MOHAMED MOHAMUD ADEN\AndroidStudioProjects\todo_fire_store> **flutterfire configure --project=simple-to-do-762ea
```

I found this as output:

> i Found 0 Firebase projects. Selecting project simple-to-do-762ea.
> FirebaseProjectNotFoundException: Firebase project id "simple-to-do-762ea" could not be found on this Firebase account.
> PS C:\Users\MOHAMED MOHAMUD ADEN\AndroidStudioProjects\todo_fire_store>

Answer (score 0):

Did you login with Firebase CLI by any chance? documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web)

```
firebase login
```

You can check all the projects listed with the firebase account you are logged in

```
firebase projects:list
```

check if your project is listed